# JavaScript calculating deposit in bank for 3 years

Tags: javascript

Problem: You have deposited a sum into your bank account for 3 years. The bank has announced an interest of 5% per year. Each time the interest is calculated and added to your deposit. You have to calculate the amount in your deposit for each year. Also I must print the number with two numbers after the decimal point.

```
let i = gets();
let input = Number(i);


let firstYear = input + (input*(5/100));
let secondYear = firstYear + (firstYear*(5/100));
let thirdYear = secondYear + (secondYear*(5/100));

let printFirst = firstYear.toFixed(2);
let printSecond = secondYear.toFixed(2);
let printThird = thirdYear.toFixed(2);

print(printFirst);
print(printSecond);
print(printThird);
```

Comment: *"You have to calculate ... Also I must print"*: I'm a bit confused who does what? Can you be explicit about the **problem** you have in doing this assignment?

Comment: I would assume he means he needs to calculate it then print it

Comment: `print(printFirst);` --> `console.log(printFirst);` ?? And what is `gets()`? Are you using a library?

Comment: Also, you are using `firstYear` in all your `toFixed` lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop like this

```
for(let i=0;i < 3;i++){ 
    sum += sum * 0.05;
    console.log(`${i} year: ${sum.toFixed(2)}`)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).